# How to write integration tests to check if the cron job runs at the right time and does the right job?

Tags: java, automation, cron, scheduled-tasks, integration-testing

I am building cron-jobs using **Quartz Framework** in my application. I am looking for any automation framework for the **integration tests** to test cron jobs.

What I want to achieve is to write a test, giving cron expression as an input and expect my test to trigger the job and assert the action.

I have looked for multiple options but couldn't find any solution.

What exactly I want to verify through integration test is:

- if the cronjob is configured correctly
- Test for the execution of the cronjob by calling the execute method directly from the test.
- Test to verify the cron format
- Break the flow of cron job
- Run multiple cron job in parallel in a test